# How to get data based on Case condition and MAX Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have some data:

```
Declare @table table (RID VARCHAR(10),
                      CommType INT,
                      CommunicationType INT,
                      VALUE VARCHAR(20),
                      lastDate Datetime)

INSERT INTO @table (RID, CommType, CommunicationType, VALUE, lastDate) 
VALUES 
('00WAAS', 3, 0, 'mohan@gmail', '2012-06-15 15:23:49.653'),
('00WAAS', 3, 1, 'manasa@gmail', '2015-08-15 15:23:49.653'),
('00WAAS', 3, 2, 'mother@gmail', '2014-09-15 15:23:49.653'),
('00WAAS', 3, 2, 'father@gmail', '2016-01-15 15:23:49.653'),
('00WAAS', 3, 0, 'hello@gmail', '2013-01-15 15:23:49.653')
```

My query:

```
SELECT 
    TT.RID,
    COALESCE(Homemail, BusinessMail, OtherMail) Mail  
FROM 
    (SELECT
         RID, MAX(Homemail) Homemail,
         MAX(BusinessMail) BusinessMail,
         MAX(OtherMail) OtherMail 
     FROM 
         (SELECT
              RID, 
              CASE 
                 WHEN CommType = 3 AND CommunicationType = 0 THEN VALUE 
              END AS Homemail,
              CASE 
                 WHEN CommType = 3 AND CommunicationType = 1 THEN VALUE 
              END AS BusinessMail,
              CASE 
                 WHEN CommType = 3 AND CommunicationType = 2 THEN VALUE 
              END AS OtherMail,
              lastDate
          FROM
              @table) T
      GROUP BY RID) TT
```

What I'm expecting

Here I need to get result if `CommType = 3 and CommunicationType = 0` then related value based on latest date and if data is not available for 
CommType = 3 and CommunicationType = 0

then I need to get data of CommunicationType = 1 
related value based on latest date and if there is no data for 
CommunicationType = 1

then CommunicationType = 2 based on latest date of that CommunicationTypes.

Here I have tried Case condition ,MAX and Coalesce

If combination data is present in CommunicationType = 0 is present get CommunicationType = 0 based on latest date

If combination data is not present in CommunicationType = 0 then get CommunicationType = 1 based on latest date

If combination data is not present in CommunicationType = 1 then get CommunicationType = 2 based on latest date

Comment: Please can you provide an example of expected results in your question?

Comment: I have told clearly my expectation please you can check my query by executing

Comment: You've explained in words what you expect. What Chris Pickford is suggesting is the resultset you expect to see based on your input data.

Comment: if you are going to execute my query result set is going to shown but as per my combinations it will fails on that I have asked the question

Comment: I agree with Chris and John.  It isn't clear.  I'm not sure I understand.  It would help if you could provide a table showing the expected output, based on the sample provided.  See the [help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more on providing useful, helpful sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, use `ROW_NUMBER()` :

```
SELECT tt.RID,COALESCE(tt.Homemail,tt.businessMail,tt.OtherMail) 
FROM(
    select s.RID,
        MAX(CASE WHEN s.CommType = 3 AND s.CommunicationType = 0 THEN s.VALUE END) AS Homemail,
        MAX(CASE WHEN s.CommType = 3 AND s.CommunicationType = 1 THEN s.VALUE END) AS BusinessMail,
        MAX(CASE WHEN s.CommType = 3 AND s.CommunicationType = 2 THEN s.VALUE END) AS OtherMail
     from (SELECT t.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.rid,t.communicationType ORDER BY t.lastDate DESC)
           FROM @table t
           WHERE t.commType = 3) s
    WHERE s.rnk = 1
    GROUP BY s.rid) tt
```

Comment: I will test and let you know the results more over I have tried with MAX(Date)OVER (partition .....)

Comment: But you don't want the last date, you want the value based on the last date, that's why I used `ROW_NUMBER()`

Comment: Thanks it's working fine my script instead of Row_number I went for MAX(lastdate)Partition show it got latest date ...@sagi

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure I've understood the requirement.  But I think you want:

1. One record returned for each RID.
2. The returned record should have a `CommType` of 3.
3. If there is more than one record with a `CommType` 3 you want the record with the lowest `CommunicationType`.
4. If there is still more than one record you want the one with the most recent `lastDate`.

This query uses the [windowed function](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-2012/how-use-microsoft-sql-server-2012s-window-functions-part-1) [ROW_NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms186734.aspx) to rank the available records, within a subquery.  [PARTITION BY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) ensures each RID is ranked sepearatly.  The outer query returns all records with a rank of 1.

**Query**

```
SELECT
    r.*
FROM
    (           
        /* For each RID We want the lowest communication type with 
         * the most recent last date.
         */
        SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RID ORDER BY CommunicationType, lastDate DESC) AS rn,
            *
        FROM
            @table
        WHERE
            CommType = 3
    ) AS r
WHERE
    r.rn = 1
;
```

**Next Steps**

This query is ok but could be better.  For example what would happen if two records had a matching `CommType`, `CommunicationType` and `lastDate`?  Reading up on the differences between [ROW_NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms186734.aspx), [RANK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx), [DENSE_RANK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx) and [NTILE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175126.aspx) will help you figure out your options here.